# Anonymous function declaration shorthand javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm wondering whether there is any way to shorten anonymous function declaration in JavaScript through the utilization of preprocessor/compiler like Google Closure. I figure it'd be quite neat for callbacks.

For example, normally I'd write a qunit test case this way:

```
test("Dummy test", function(){ ok( a == b );});
```

I'm looking for some Clojure-inspired syntax as followed:

```
test("Dummy test", #(ok a b));
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Try CoffeeScript with its shorten functions via ->  ( http://coffeescript.org/#literals )

Comment: OMG another question. Where has it been all my life? :) But for the sake of exhausting all options, I'll leave the question opened to see if there is any Closure plugin which can accomplish the same task. Thanks though.

Comment: Since Closure uses an actual JavaScript parser to parse its input, I think that plugins are probably a bit constrained in what they can accomplish. There's no way to parse `#(ok a b)` as JavaScript.

Comment: What about this? `test("Dummy test", () => ok( a == b ));`

Comment: @FDisk it's perfect. Could you travel to 2013, tell the ES6 committee to finalize the specification then and write up babel so I can use it on IE8?

Comment: @LimH. As a fallback you can use preprocessors like http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without worrying about preprocessors or compilers, you could do the following which shortens the callback syntax. One thing with this is that the scope of "this" isn't dealt with...but for your use case I don't think that's important:

```
var ok = function(a,b) {
  return (a==b);
};

var f = function(func) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

  return function() {
    return func.apply(undefined,args);
  };
};

/*
Here's your shorthand syntax
*/
var callback = f(ok,10,10);

console.log(callback());
```